# How to embed a part of a website in webview UWP

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Is it possible to embed only a specific portion inside of a page(i.e. div) on the WebView control in UWP?

Comment: Может это поможет:
[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537299/how-to-set-hard-coded-html-in-uwp-webview)

Answer (score 3):

The webview doesn't include an address bar and so will only show pages that you load or can be navigated to from those pages. If you can control what is loaded you can show only the pages you wish.

If you don't have control over the HTML of the site, you could prevent access to pages you don't want by handling the [`NavigationStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_NavigationStarting) event and canceling the navigation if it's to a page you don't want displaying.

Answer (score 1):

No, assuming by a "portion" of a website you mean a portion within a page. However as Matt said, if you only want to show a certain page, you can of course navigate to the relevant web page and then control what navigation links you allow through his method.

If you did indeed mean only a portion within a page, the options aren't attractive. Theoretically you could pull down the html of a site with an Http request and then parse it to filter out what you didn't want, store it locally, and then load that local page in the webview. However I think it would add significant overhead, could create conflicts with javascript or whatever else the site might be using, among other things. But hey maybe if it's a very targeted use-case you might be able to play with it.

If in your scenario though you also control said website the app is accessing, then I'd just enable specific URLs to offer up the desired versions of your site when the app requests 'em.

Answer (score 1):

Note 100% sure, but i can give a hit to embed external part of a any html content to a website opened in webview control.

```
var result = await this.webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });

string result = await this.webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new [] {"document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;" });
```

Add HTML content through java script.

Hope that will help