# How to set hard coded HTML in UWP WebView

Tags: webview, uwp

I have some hard coded html:

```
string myHtml = "<html>some html</html>"
```

How can I set it as my WebView source? Something like this:

```
webView.HtmlSource = myHtml;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we use `WebView.NavigateToString(htmlstring);` to load and display html string. For source of WebView, only apply for Uri parameters. But you can create an attached property like HtmlSource for WebView and when it changes to call NavigateToString to load.

```
public class MyWebViewExtention
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlSourceProperty =
           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HtmlSource", typeof(string), typeof(MyWebViewExtention), new PropertyMetadata("", OnHtmlSourceChanged));
    public static string GetHtmlSource(DependencyObject obj) { return (string)obj.GetValue(HtmlSourceProperty); }
    public static void SetHtmlSource(DependencyObject obj, string value) { obj.SetValue(HtmlSourceProperty, value); }
    private static void OnHtmlSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView webView = d as WebView;
        if (webView != null)
        {
            webView.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
 }
```

.xaml:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" local:MyWebViewExtention.HtmlSource="{x:Bind myHtml,Mode=OneWay}"></WebView>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Binding HTML to a WebView with Attached Properties](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2013/09/26/binding-html-to-a-webview-with-attached-properties/).